# flask, jinja2: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'ngettext' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, gettext

I am writing a small flask app. This is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from jinja2 import Environment

from towngen import generate_settlement


app = Flask(__name__)
jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])
app.jinja_options['extensions'].append('jinja2.ext.i18n')

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template("settlement.html", settlement=generate_settlement())
```

Inside of the template I use:

```
    {% trans count=settlement.features|length %}
    The settlement has {apnumber(count)} unique features:
    {% pluralize %}
    The settlement has {apnumber(count)} unique features:
    {% endtrans %}
```

This throws an exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/gru/Code/towngen/web.py", line 13, in hello_world
    return render_template("settlement.html", settlement=generate_settlement())
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/Users/gru/.venvs/towngen/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/gru/Code/towngen/templates/settlement.html", line 12, in top-level template code
    {% trans count=settlement.features|length %}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'ngettext' is undefined
```

Have I mis-configured something? I can't find a doc that would plainly describe how to add that extension.